# Full colored Triangle and Circle in Metapost

Tags: graphics, color, metapost

The question may be trivial, but I need your help, to draw a full colored triangle and circle (where the triangle will be inside the circle).

Here is my file `pic_1.mp`:

```
input gjktc.mp;

u:=1mm;

beginfig(1);

z0=(0,0);
z1=(20u,0);
z2=(10u,20u);

draw z0..z1..z2..cycle withcolor green;
draw z0--z1--z2--cycle withcolor red;
endfig;
end;
```

And the next one, `pic_2.mp`, where the one line will be rotated, and the space between lines will be colored:

```
input gjktc.mp;

u:=1mm;

beginfig(1);

z0=(0,0);
z1=(20u,0);
z2=(10u,10u);

p1 = z0--z1--z2--cycle ;
draw p1 withcolor black;
draw (z2--z0) rotated 5 withcolor black;

endfig;
end;
```

Here is a picture of what I want to have:

[image]

Comment: You need the "fill" command.  Otherwise most of the code looks roughly what is required. (More specific: where you have "draw ... withcolor ..." try "fill ... withcolor ..."

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I need. And if you will see at the second picture, there is black lines and spaces are colored differently. I have a problem with red part. I have something like this, but it is doesnt work.
p2= (z2--z0) rotated 5;

draw p2 withcolor black;
fill p2--z2 withcolor blue;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
prologues := 3;        % Make metapost write EPS files
u := 1mm;

outputtemplate := "pic%c.eps";  % set the filename template - %c picks up the fig #

beginfig(1);
z0=(10u,0) rotated 90;  % use "rotated" to get a nice equilateral triangle easily
z1=z0 rotated 120; z2 = z0 rotated -120;
fill z0..z1..z2..cycle withcolor green; 
fill z0--z1--z2--cycle withcolor red;
endfig;

beginfig(2);  % second fig can be in the same file 
z0=(0,0);
z1=(20u,0);
z2=(10u,10u);
z3 = whatever[z0,z2 rotated 5] = whatever[z1,z2]; % read mpman.pdf for "whatever"

path p[];  % you must declare paths
p1 = z0--z1--z2--cycle;
p2 = z0--z2--z3--cycle;

fill p1 withcolor green;  % fill before you draw (in general)
fill p2 withcolor red;
draw p1 withcolor black;
draw p2 withcolor black;

endfig;
end;
```

I've added some notes as comments in the code.

pic1.eps = [image]  pic2.eps = [image]

Comment: You should use `outputtemplate` instead of `filenametemplate` (the latter is considered deprecated since MetaPost version 1.200).

Comment: @karlkoeller thanks, will fix.  Old habits die hard.